# Dynamically fetch images online based on a keyword (specifically a city or country)

Tags: java, image, gwt, google-image-search

I'm developing a web application that deals with travel. I want to be able to fetch a picture (or multiple pictures) of a particular geo-location and display it to the user.

I've done some searching and found a couple of possible solutions, unfortunately my first choice (Google Image Search) is deprecated.

Preferably, I'd like a client-side GWT library, but if that's not an option, then a Java library would suffice.

Any suggestions?

The basic purpose is to have a picture for every city/country that a user wants to travel to. If there is another, simpler, way of achieving this task, please let me know (I know that scraping the web for images and saving them locally is an option, but not only is it illegal, it is also very inefficient and error prone -- so that's not an option).

Thanks,

Vladimir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the Google Street View Image API? Simply construct a URL in accordance with the documentation, and the Google Street View Image API returns the corresponding image.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/